# Simple PHP script for XZ file download

Tags: php, download, http-headers

I'm trying to setup a backup system that will perform a backup, compress the file and make it downloadable from a browser. The file downloads properly but when I try to uncompress it I get:

`unxz: backup_2015-08-12.txz: File format not recognized`

There is a backup script that will output

`/tmp/agribackup.txz`

The PHP script is as follows:

```
<?php
// Create the agribackup.txz file
$e = shell_exec("/usr/local/bin/agribackup.sh");

$file = '/tmp/agribackup.txz';

if(file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/xz');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup_'.date("Y-m-d") . '.txz');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: why not compress it via php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the wrong Content-Type. Refering to 'http://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format.txt', the correct MIME-type is '**application/x-xz**'.